# how to delete the file using method of ofstream using c++?

Tags: c++

I am using ofstream to output to a file which I then want to erase at the end of my program. Is there a method of fstream or anything that allows me to delete the file ?

Comment: [Filesystem library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) available in C++17. For now you can use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) or stick to platform specific apis.

Answer (score 6):

The std::fstream doesn't provides filesystem operations, it provides file operations only.

You can use the C [stdio remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/) that should work with most compilers :

```
/* remove example: remove myfile.txt */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  if( remove( "myfile.txt" ) != 0 )
     perror( "Error deleting file" );
  else
    puts( "File successfully deleted" );
  return 0;
}
```